# ASIHTTPRequest Custom Progress Tracking

Tags: iphone, ios, protocols, asihttprequest

I've read about implementing custom progress tracking in my app using ASIHTTPRequest in the [documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#downloading_the_response_directly_to_a_file). It mentions implementing 2 methods, `request:didReceiveBytes:` and `request:incrementDownloadSizeBy:`. I have added these to my view controller but they are not being called. I'm just trying to get the sample code working at this point.

```
// ViewController.m

- (void)fetchThisURLFiveTimes:(NSURL *)url
{
    [myQueue cancelAllOperations];
    [myQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
    [myQueue setDelegate:self];
    [myQueue setRequestDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueComplete:)];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        request.showAccurateProgress = YES;
        [myQueue addOperation:request];
    }
    myQueue.showAccurateProgress = YES;
    [myQueue go];
}

- (void)queueComplete:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue
{
   NSLog(@"Value: %f", [myProgressIndicator progress]);
}

- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveBytes:(long long)bytes
{
    NSLog(@"bytes: %lld", bytes);
}

- (void)request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request incrementDownloadSizeBy:(long long)newLength
{
    NSLog(@"newLength: %lld", newLength);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I believe the error is coming because you're mixing the queue delegates with the ASIHTTPRequest ones!The methods you mentioned are supposed to work only with ASIHTTPRequest!Check this section on ASI support page 'About ASINetworkQueues'

Comment: Are you saying that these methods can only be used with an ASIHTTPRequest, not an ASINetworkQueue? The ASINetworkQueue contains multiple ASIHTTPRequest objects so I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. So where you place the line `self.myQueue.showAccurateProgress = YES;` is really important. It has to be added before the line `[self.myQueue addOperation:request];`. Here is what worked for me.

```
- (void)fetchThisURLFiveTimes:(NSURL *)url
{
    [self.myQueue cancelAllOperations];        
    [self setMyQueue:[ASINetworkQueue queue]];
    [self.myQueue setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];
    [self.myQueue setDelegate:self];
    [self.myQueue setQueueDidFinishSelector:@selector(queueFinished:)];
    self.myQueue.showAccurateProgress = YES;

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.myQueue addOperation:request];
    }
    [self.myQueue go];
}

- (void)queueFinished:(ASINetworkQueue *)queue
{
    if ([self.myQueue requestsCount] == 0) {
        [self setMyQueue:nil];
    }
    NSLog(@"Queue finished");
}

- (void)setProgress:(float)newProgress {
    NSLog(@"progress: %f", newProgress);
}
```

What a waste of 6 hours trying to figure this out. I hope this saves someone some aggravation.